# Hybris, export homepage with all its data using Impex Export

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I want to export **homepage**(*main page, that one which has navigation panel with categories, banners etc*) and all data related to it.
So far I have managed to migrate category navigation panel at the top, by exporting impex with the following CMS types:
**CategoryNavigationComponent, CMSNavigationNode, CMSLinkComponent, CMSNavigationEntry**. But I'm confused how to export the rest of the page.
The best scenario will be to migrate only the data related to homepage. But if it will be easier, we can download all the other pages data as well, it will be good too.
Is there some universal way to do it, which types would you transfer?

Versions of hybris,

- Source server: 6.4
- Target server: 6.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no quick and easy way to export components related to a specific page. At the minimum, you'll need to know what those components are.

If you want to export all components / Types, SAP Commerce 1905's back office has "System > Tools > Script Generator". THere might be something similar in SAP Commerce 6.4 (not sure if this already using backoffice or HMC). However, you will need to review the script and adjust accordingly, since some of them will cause errors when you try to import the exported data.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this approach. "System > Tools > Script Generator" exists in SAP Commerce 6.4 too.
For others struggling with the same problem, I have tried to export components related to pages in a different way, by exporting manually the components involed on page/s and relationships between them. But you will face a lot of errors with references like this: "cannot resolve value 'componentRef232' for attribute 'cmsComponents'". In my case there were hundreds of custom component types and references to them.
So, it seems better to export it all in one go